# Add new line with HTML bubble info

Tags: html, infobubble

I'm improving my web application by adding bubbles information at different places.

I have the following example :

```
<h4><b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Something 
    <a><span title="Some advices ..."
            class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span></a>
</b> </h4>
```

How I can add a newline in my `title class` in order to get :

```
Some advices
Some others informations
```

and not

```
Some advices. Some others informations
```

Thank you

Comment: options 1) style like a list (`<ul>`) 2) append `<br>` with js 3) use data-attributes instead of classes 4) css `display: block;` for titled `span`'s (`div`'s?)

Comment: I used option 4 and it works pretty well. Thank you ;) Maybe add your message as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this result you can use `div`'s instead of `span`'s, as they have `display: block;` styling, unlike span's.